# Multiple replacing of HTML tags from textbox while inserting to db

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So, I know how to do it with one thing like br

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", TextBox1.Text.Replace("\n", "<br/>"));
```

But how can I add multiple replacements to it? I've tried..

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", TextBox1.Text.Replace("\n", "<br/>").Replace("\b", "<b/>"));
```

But it does not work, gave me an error back

@Edit

the error I got

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected
```

this is what I had inside of the textbox

```
test</b>
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @diiN_ edited post

Comment: It should work. But btw. why do you want to replace a backspace \b with a line break? Maybe you tried to replace \r with an line break;

Comment: @Sammy what does \r mean? I thought you could replace it with whatever you want, is there any list of those? I want to replace </br> with \n and </b> with \b

Comment: \r and \n is used in windows for a line break

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client as possible duplicate

Comment: you have swapped the parameter `replace(string old, string new)`

Comment: @Sammy Yes, that is what I want.. I just wasn't thinking when I was writing it probably. I need a way yet to replace </b> wrritten into something... but nothing seems to wrosk..</br> works well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your textbox value like this, you could try adding `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` to your web.config. Or maybe adding `<pages validateRequest="false" />` to the `<system.web>` block inside your web.config would help you get rid of the error message.

Btw. if you want to replace `</br>` with `\n` you're doing it the wrong way. `.Replace("\n", "</br>")` replaces `\n` with `</br>`.

Comment: and how would you replace just <b> and </b>. I don't wanna enable whole html on the page

Comment: I would say `.Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", "\b")`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you simply need to disable validation. Add this to the top of your aspx page:

`<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>`

Bear in mind that this is default true to protect your page from script attacks. Read this for more information: http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation

But for what you are trying to do this should do the trick, although I would not recommend in an application where security is a concern.

**edit**

For completeness sake, I think you can do something else without disabling the validation.

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text).Replace("\n", "<br/>").Replace("\b", "<b/>"));
```

By the way, I think the last Replace won't do anything to the example text you posted, but that's out of the scope of the question I suppose.

Comment: Ok, I understood the whole point f it now. I just have to make my own bbcode for easier use experiance  : D